# EF6 Read uncommitted data

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I need to perform a transaction like below:

1. Start transaction: Here I call `context.Database.BeginTransaction()` (please note the `context` here is not the same one below in the question where I want to read uncommitted)
2. Save a contact (done using a stored procedure): This usp has a transaction as well.
3. Create some other records based on the contact (done using EF application side)
4. Commit

The issue I am running into is that in step 3, I need to read some data from the database which has not been committed yet (from step 2). I tried doing this but it is not working:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
var contact = context.Contact.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactId == intId);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;");
```

I have the debugger running and pause at the point where the `contact` is being fetched, but nothing is returned.

If I query for the same record in SSMS (sql server mgmt studio), it returns result:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select * from Contact c where c.ContactId = 9999
```

**Questions**

1. How can I read uncommitted data using EF6? Some searches online lead me to create a custom interceptor but do I really need to?
2. Many articles suggest not to read uncommitted data but I cannot think of another way to achieve this. Is there?

Comment: What actually is the step 1? If you do `var tr = context.Database.BeginTransaction();` then the future operations using the same `context` should see the uncommitted changes in that transaction.

Comment: @IvanStoev it is simply `this.context.Database.BeginTransaction();` but this is not the same context as the one in the question.

Comment: I see. Then try `BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)`, it seem to work (quick test).

Comment: @IvanStoev I have tried that but that did not work either. Do you think it is because there are multiple transactions? One is started at the application using `BeginTransaction`, and there is one at the stored procedure level? In other words, a transaction within a transaction.

Comment: Might be. In my test I used 2 db contexts and 2 (application level) transactions.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a little dated, but just hoping it will shed light for someone else. I'm under the impression that setting the isolation level inside ExecuteSqlCommand is useless since it would only affect that 1 statement. ExecuteSqlCommand would start its own transaction. Try the following to start a new read uncommitted transaction within the scope of your other transaction:

```
Contact contact;
using (var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    contact = context.Contact.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactId == intId);
    trans.Commit(); // not sure if this matters for a read
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try wrapping your database access code in a `TransactionScope`, like so:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
```

How are you starting your transaction? I ask because if the code flow is as you described all the operations in steps 2 and 3 should be done within the same transaction and that transaction should be able to see any changes that were made by previous operations within the same transaction.

You might also try using SQL Server Profiler to watch the database interaction and see if additional (new) transactions are being created.

It might help if you posted the actual code that does steps 1 through 4.

Comment: I have edited my question and yes there are other transactions.

Comment: When I try that with an injected DBContext, I get a the following error:
A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread that it was created.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, I would use context.Database.BeginTransaction instead of TransactionScope if all your logic is database related. If you have other operations outside of EF, that's when I would use TransactionScope as this is a .NET feature vs a transaction created in the database.